# Gh-pages not displaying the right thing

Tags: github-pages-deploy-action

I'm having some issues with getting the proper page to display. I've looked up different answers and they don't seem to be working for me.

https://github.com/samus94/portfolio2.1

Please let me know what I've done wrong here.
It was displaying the readme before, and I think it still is.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what problem are you facing?

Answer (score 0):

First, You've posted a link to your GitHub repository, not your GitHub Page. The address for GitHub pages always looks like `https://<yourname>.github.io/<reponame>`.

To get this URL you can go into the settings for your repo and find the GitHub Pages section. Make sure you have GitHub Pages enabled, then look for the URL your site is published at.

[image: github pages config]

Finally, GitHub Pages requires your repository have a very specific structure. It expects there to be an `index.html` file at the root of the repository. This means you have to either move everything in your `/src` directory to the root, or move the `index.html` and update the URLs to your javascript and CSS.

All of these requirements are outlined clearly in the [GitHub Pages documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/working-with-github-pages).

Comment: Sry, yes I should've included the link for the GitHub Page (https://samus94.github.io/portfolio2.1/) . I'll try moving the files in my /src directory to the root and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Deploying static HTML + CSS + JS sites (**NO jekyll**) to Github Pages,
using Github Actions was harder than I though.
Theres is very few *quality*  documentation about this specific topic, except [this one:](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/continuously-deploy-static-pages-with-github-actions-gh-pages-207e4a009d1c)

Steps overview:

1. Setup a custom action in github
2. Push changes and the action executes automatically
3. Your page is deployed to github pages

One important thing: I had no need of changing any property in the yml; don't worry about customizations.